# Best practices for top-level domains in directory structure

Tags: apache, web, server

I am researching the process on how to setup multiple websites from the same VPS. I have noticed that in many cases I have seen online, the directory folders are named to include the top-level domain.

Say you are serving **example.com** out of **/var/www/example.com/**. What is the reasoning for including the TLD in the directory name?

Wouldn’t it make more sense to just name it as **/var/www/example/**? For instance, if they wanted to later change the domain to *example.net*, they wouldn’t need to update the directory name.

Comment: I have a single box that serves 20+ domain names. I use `/data/sites/org/example/www`. This is entirely opinion based and up-to-you on your specific organizational structure. If your box will only ever serve a single domain, then you can opt to not even include it at all.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for others, but I do this myself, so I'll answer from my perspective. Having a full domain name is a good practice because

1. You (or some other admin) don't have to guess
2. There can never be any conflicts such as between example.com and example.net existing simultaneously
3. If you are automating things, scripts are simpler because you can avoid extra level of mapping. (similar to point 1, but for computers)